# Request URL and make directory error in python

Tags: python

This programs runs but gives back no output.Doesn't create a new folder or download the images from URLs.

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os    
def store_raw_images():
    neg_images_link = 'http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n07942152'   
    neg_image_urls = urllib.request.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()
    pic_num = 1
    
    if not os.path.exists('neg'):
        os.makedirs('neg')
        
    for i in neg_image_urls.split('\n'):
        try:
            print(i)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(i, "neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg")
            img = cv2.imread("neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            # should be larger than samples / pos pic (so we can place our image on it)
            resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
            cv2.imwrite("neg/"+str(pic_num)+".jpg",resized_image)
            pic_num += 1
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
store_raw_images()
```

what is going wrong here?

i get this error when i run this in IDLE.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Training images\download_images.py", line 26, in <module>
    store_raw_images()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Training images\download_images.py", line 8, in store_raw_images
    neg_image_urls = urllib.request.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 501, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 320, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 346, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 375, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: '//image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n07942152'
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to run it.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    store_raw_images()
```

Comment: Yes, i ran it with store_raw_images() but still get the same error

Comment: @TarunReddy The code you posted runs for me without issue. Are you sure you didn't modify `neg_images_link`?

Comment: no i haven't changed anything.But still getting the same error. I think problem is with the requests module according to the error

Comment: @TarunReddy the error you posted implies you have a  malformed url.. `neg_images_link` is missing the protocol `http:`